# Unknown type name 'CGFloat' when try to add PanoramaGL to the static library

Tags: ios, objective-c

I try to use `panoramaGL` framework and try to add it to my static library. So I've imported it to the project, add `CoreGraphics` framework but have an issue `Unknown type name 'CGFloat'` in PLStructs.h. When I Cmd+click on the `CGFloat` in Xcode - I go to the `CGBase.h` in `CoreGraphics` framework. Try to clean the project and replace the frameworks  - the result is the same. Waiting for your help.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The solution is simple:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

Comment: I had this issue when adding a new target. Due to project conventions I had to first set up a .pch file with this and similar import statements, then add it to the build settings.

Answer (score 27):

Also don't need a full CoreGraphics.h. This is enough:

```
#import <CoreGraphics/CGBase.h>
```

Answer (score 13):

You actually don't need to import the full `UIKit`. This is enough:

```
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
```

Answer (score 2):

The same problem came for me in Cocos2D.

The solution is

1. Go to build settings. In **Architectures** field you might have "Standard architectures (armv7, armv7s, arm64).
2. The main cause for the problem is arm64. So the best way is to use "**armv7**" in the field.
3. We keep the standard architecture as is n "**valid architectures**"

Hope it helps.