# Attempting to use FBShimmer cocoa pod on iOS but not finding Foundation framework

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am Attempting to use FBShimmer cocoa pod on iOS but not finding Foundation framework.[PodFile shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQqG2.png)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to uncomment use_frameworks! from your podfile, then install again. It might help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24750593/unknown-type-name-cgfloat-when-try-to-add-panoramagl-to-the-static-library/27902361

Comment: @AaqibHussain I tried that but then the header files listed in the bridging header weren't being found .

Comment: Remove Shimmer.h from your bridging header. Since you're using use_frameworks. You don't really need it. then try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using a UIView extension to achieve the same effect. Much less code and no external dependency.

```
func startShimmering() {
    let light = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5).cgColor
    let dark = UIColor.white.cgColor

    let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.colors = [dark, light, dark]
    gradient.frame = CGRect(x: -self.bounds.size.width, y: 0, width: 3*self.bounds.size.width, height: self.bounds.size.height)
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.4)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    gradient.locations = [0.4, 0.5, 0.6]
    self.layer.mask = gradient

    let animation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "locations")
    animation.fromValue = [0.0, 0.1, 0.2]
    animation.toValue = [0.8, 0.9, 1.0]

    animation.duration = 3.0
    animation.repeatCount = HUGE
    gradient.add(animation, forKey: "shimmer")


}
```